# Sorting a two-dimensional array in Perl based on value of one item, with exceptions

Tags: perl, sorting

Currently, I am working with a two dimensional array with information on soccer goals scored. Each item in the first array is an array with different information regarding the goal. The second item in this array is the minute scored (1-90) because I want them in sequential order so I can determine what they made the scoreline. I'm using that 'minutes' value to sort with this:

```
@allinfogoals = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @allinfogoals;
```

This works great, until I run into goals that were scored in extra time. The minutes for these are displayed like "90+2" or "45+3". Now, I can just add them together, but that could make the order incorrect. In this case, a goal scored right before half time could be stored as having been scored AFTER a goal that was scored shortly after the beginning of the second half.

So, I'm finding the minutes that have this 90+x format and splitting them at the '+'. I'm storing the first value where I regularly store minutes in the array, but I added another at the end of the array (12th item) and I'm putting that second part (mins into extra time) there. That is 0 when it is a regular goal.

How can I modify the sorting above to compensate this and have it maintain the proper order?

Comment: These kinds of problems are much better described by providing sample input and expected output than by using three paragraphs worth of words.

Comment: Good point. Sorry. It's even more involved in the code, so I just picked the one part that I need to figure out and explained instead.

Comment: Does `45` mean last minute of first half, first minute of second half, or both?

Comment: In soccer, 45 means that regular time (45 mins per half) for the first half has passed, and they give a few minutes of extra time so as to not end abruptly. However, when someone scores then, it is displayed as 45+whatever minute. If someone scored between 44:00 and 44:59, it would still be considered the 45th minute.

Comment: So basically 45 means first period no matter what. And a goal scored at 45:12 in the second period would be 46.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. So I don't really need to worry about it getting confused with the second half. However, if a goal is scored at 44:30 (would be listed as min 45), and another in extra time (45+x) I want to make sure that the regular time one gets sorted as coming before the extra time goal.

Comment: In a comment below you said "No, 45+2 is still the second half", which directly contradicts what you just said here. Why don't you edit your question to state the rules clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to sort on one key first, and if that key is the same, then you want to sort on a second key.

E.g. you want 45+2 to be sorted between 45 and 46.

You can do this by simply using:

```
@ls = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] || $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @ls
```

Only if the first key is the same, the second key is consulted.

Here is a complete example:

```
my @allinfogoals=(
                  [ 46, 0 ],
                  [ 45, 2 ],
                  [ 45, 0 ],
                  [ 33, 0 ],
                  [ 91, 0 ],
                  [ 90, 2 ],
                 );

@allinfogoals=sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] || $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @allinfogoals;

use Data::Dump; dd \@allinfogoals;
```

And the output is:

```
[[33, 0], [45, 0], [45, 2], [46, 0], [90, 2], [91, 0]]
```

Comment: No, 45+2 is still the first half. After extra time (a few minutes, which '2' is a part of) ends, they start the second half at 45:00 again. What I'm trying to do is make sure I still sort the goals sequentially given this information

Comment: Comments with me and TLP on original post would help clarify.

Comment: 45+2 is the second minute of overtime in the first half, and 46 is the second minute of the second half, right? By the same logic, 90+2 is the second minute of the overtime of the second half, but what is 91? Before or after 90+2? Ah, ok, 91 is the second minute of the extended play (in case of a tournament where a draw isn't a valid result). Ok, then this should work.

Comment: My apologies, 45+2 is still the first half. Typo

Comment: Looks to be working perfectly. Thanks. Sorry to you and TLP for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "brute force" solution, in that there's not much finesse in it, but does the job. It does not work with a two-dimensional data structure unless adapted, but on the other hand, I don't know what your data structure looks like.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @data = qw(22 45+3 45 46 90 90+3);

my @sorted = map $_->[2],               # turn back to org string
        sort {
            $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] ||      # default sort by period number
            $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]         # or by minute
        } map mysort($_), @data;        # map all minutes to 3-element array

say for @sorted;

sub mysort {
    my $time = shift;
    if ($time =~ /45\+(\d+)/) {
        return [1, 45+$1, $time];
    } elsif ($time =~ /90\+(\d+)/) {
        return [2, 90+$1, $time];
    } else {
        my $period = ($time <= 45 ? 1 : 2);
        return [$period, $time, $time]
    }
}
```

This uses a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to turn each minute entry into a three element array, consisting of period number, minute within that period and the original string. The output of this script is:

```
22
45
45+3
46
90
90+3
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, as you have described it, you could also (as someone answered but deleted again, it seems) convert your overtime minutes to tenths and order numerically:

```
my @allinfogoals=qw(46 45+2 45 33 91 90+2);

@allinfogoals=map { s/[.]/+/; $_ } sort { $a <=> $b } map { s/[+]/./; $_ } @allinfogoals;

use Data::Dump; dd \@allinfogoals;
```

... and then convert back. Output:

```
[33, 45, "45+2", 46, "90+2", 91]
```